# how to successfully import ldap3 (0.9.8.4) in python 3.10 / windows 10

Tags: python, ldap

i am using Python 3.10 and want to make a LDAP connection.
so i tried ldap3(0.9.8.4).

my project runs in an venv.

my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\Lib\\site-packages\\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4')
import pyasn1
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from ldap3 import Connection


#server = Server('ip')
#con=Connection(server,'user','password',auto_bind=True)
#print(con)
```

the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\myldap.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ldap3 import Connection
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\Lib\site-packages\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4\ldap3\__init__.py", line 254, in <module>
    from .core.server import Server
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\Lib\site-packages\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4\ldap3\core\server.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..protocol.rfc4512 import SchemaInfo, DsaInfo
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\Lib\site-packages\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4\ldap3\protocol\rfc4512.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ..utils.conv import escape_bytes, json_hook, check_json_dict, format_json, check_escape
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\Lib\site-packages\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4\ldap3\utils\conv.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..utils.ciDict import CaseInsensitiveDict
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\Lib\site-packages\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4\ldap3\utils\ciDict.py", line 31, in <module>
    class CaseInsensitiveDict(collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

i used `from collections.abc import MutableMapping` after i've got the same error while only importing sys, pyasn1 and ldap3.

my installed modules:

```
altgraph==0.17.2
click @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
cmake @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/cmake-3.22.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl
colorama @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cycler @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl
Cython @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Cython-3.0.0a9-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Flask @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
fonttools @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/fonttools-4.29.0-py3-none-any.whl
future==0.18.2
imutils==0.5.4
itsdangerous @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Jinja2 @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
kiwisolver @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/kiwisolver-1.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
MarkupSafe @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
matplotlib @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/matplotlib-3.5.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
numpy @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
opencv-python @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/opencv_python-4.5.5-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
packaging==21.3
paho-mqtt==1.6.1
pefile==2021.9.3
Pillow @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Pillow-9.0.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
pyasn1 @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pyasn1-modules @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pyinstaller==5.0.dev0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.5
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
python3-ldap==0.9.8.4
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
scikit-build==0.12.0
six @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Werkzeug @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Werkzeug-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

may be some can help me making a ldap connection ?

Greetings
Chorum

Comment: if i change the line `collections.MutableMapping` in `collections.abc.MutableMapping` 
i get a syntax error: 
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\Lib\site-packages\python3-ldap-0.9.8.4\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 53
    from ..strategy.async import AsyncStrategy
                    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I think Idap3 0.9.8.3 is an older version of python10. If you try the latest could solve your problem.
`pip install ldap3`
This is working fine for me. and creating a successful connection.
if you need any help please comment below.

Comment: I have to work on something else today. but i will need the help tomorrow :) which version are you using?

Comment: The version i am using here is version 2.9.1. you can also use anyother version but not 0.9.8.3. as it it oldest. either you can install python 3.7 or 3.8 for it to work.

Comment: i tried  ldap3-2.9.1 with python 3.10 and it works :) Now i have to find out how i authenticate a user. Thanks for hint to 2.9.1 !

Comment: mhm i can connect to our (old) ldap but not to our ldaps.
i will start a new question...